# Long equation with parentheses inside?

Tags: equations, align

I have a formula that is very long, while at the same time, there is a big parenthesis containing the whole formula, the formula is shown as follows:

```
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle +|10\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle +|10\rangle \right) -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle -|10\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle -|10\rangle \right) -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle +|11\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle +|11\rangle \right) +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle -|11\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle -|11\rangle \right) \right)
```

I don't know how to split it into multi-lines. The double slash or split method seems useless because every time I tried to use that method, there's an error showing that cannot find `\right)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this may be using `breqn` package. The use of `{}`s is to override the default behavior of `breqn` and force line break at some point. Be warned, however, that this package has many incompatibily issues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
\frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle +|10\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle +|10\rangle \right) -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle -|10\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |01\rangle -|10\rangle \right)} -{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle +|11\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle +|11\rangle \right) +\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle -|11\rangle \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |00\rangle -|11\rangle \right)} \right) 
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This still can be much improved by taking all these `1/sqrt(2)` out of the parentheses.

```
\begin{dmath}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\Bigl[( |01\rangle +|10\rangle) (|01\rangle +|10\rangle) -(|01\rangle -|10\rangle) (|01\rangle -|10\rangle) -(|00\rangle +|11\rangle) (|00\rangle +|11\rangle) +( |00\rangle -|11\rangle) (|00\rangle -|11\rangle) \Bigr] 
\end{dmath}
```

[image]

At this point, you can get rid of `breqn` and use much better alternatives, like `multline`, `alligned`, `gathered`, etc. Notice also the removal of all unnecessary `\left .. \right`s and the use of breakable brackets using `\Bigl .. \Bigr`.

```
\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt2}\Bigl[(|01\rangle +|10\rangle) ( |01\rangle +|10\rangle ) -( |01\rangle -|10\rangle) (|01\rangle -|10\rangle) \\ -( |00\rangle +|11\rangle) ( |00\rangle +|11\rangle) +( |00\rangle -|11\rangle) (|00\rangle -|11\rangle) \Bigr] 
\end{multline}
```

[image]